# Can I just use blob urls instead of webrtc stuff?

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io, blob, webrtc

So what I am thinking is to get the blob url for each time a user signs on. A user will accept the camera thing, and it will display the user's webcam live.

Now, when the user clicks on connect (to another user to talk via webcam), I will add both users' blob urls to my database (I'm just doing this locally for now), and then set the source of the remote video to a blob url from the database.

This way I don't even really have to do any of the webrtc stuff... Is this even possible? Webrtc stuff just looks really confusing.

Comment: Interesting question, but blob URLs only work locally. They aren't shared between different users or servers

Comment: Perhaps I can use some other kind of URLs? Instead of using webrtc, can't I just set a URL source to the remote video? I'm wondering if this will technically work.

Comment: You could set it to a video coming from a server. If you want to connect to another user directly, then I'm afraid WebRTC is your only option. There are probably some tools/libraries that make it easier, but the problem of peer-to-peer communication is fundamentally non-trivial.